# How to call arcpy.RefreshActiveView() every 5 seconds using ArcGIS Python?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, excel

I have an Excel macro that generates random values after every 5 secs and I am reading it in ArcGIS for Desktop... to refresh the view I have to press f5 and the view gets updated. Now I want to automate it and run the loop infinitely. I found the command for refreshing the view is

```
arcpy.RefreshActiveView();
```

I want to call this function after a delay of 5 seconds.. I tried this code

```
import arcpy;
import time;

while True:
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView();
    time.sleep(5);
```

But the problem is when I run this the main thread is blocked and the program is not responding. So I tried to move it to a new thread.

```
import arcpy;
import time;
from threading import Thread;

def refView() :
    while True:
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView();
        time.sleep(5);

try:
    Thread(target=refView, args=()).start();
except Exception, errtxt:
    print errtxt;
```

This is also not working and the application becomes not responding, please let me know what I am doing wrong ...

Comment: Your first code snippet is correct, but it is an infinite loop though. In your question you say you want it to run infinitely, but are you sure? Do you perhaps mean you want it to run for an extended period of time and then stop?

Comment: yes i want to run in infinitely.. my code actually blocks the UI thread.. I want to switch to another thread, in order to keep the UI Responsive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Threading doesn't work with most UI manipulation in Windows as UI elements have thread affinity, which is probably why the map view is failing to refresh.

I've got a [Python project that does this in ArcGIS without threading on Github](https://github.com/jasonbot/pyaddin-interval-caller). It uses the Win32 event loop in the main thread to do timed calls in an add-in extension. You can also use it independently of add-ins by using the [`tickextension.call_layer.CallQueue`](https://github.com/jasonbot/pyaddin-interval-caller/blob/master/tickextension/call_later.py#L42-114) class:

```
import tickextension.call_later

class Refresher(tickextension.call_later.CallQueue):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Refresher, self).__init__()
        self.call_later(self.refresh_view, 5.0)
    def refresh_view(self):
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
        # Tell self to be called later again
        self.call_later(self.refresh_view, 5.0)

refresh_object = Refresher()

# Do some work
...
# turn off timer
refresh_object.active = False
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting an error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\tickextension\call_later.py", line 104, in _flush
    if id(fn) in self._cancel_list:
AttributeError: 'CallQueue' object has no attribute '_cancel_list'"

Comment: I commented the two cancel_lists line and it works :) Thanks!